# visualize metrics from a postgres db on grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I want to visualize some metrics from my postgres db on grafana. 
I installed a modified version of grafana that supports postgres datasource and I can now enter my postgres database as a datasource for my metrics.

The problem is that when I go to the panel inorder to have graphs for my metrics and I choose the column and table ... that I want to plot I get this error:

```
"message: "Data error: pq: relation "\public.table_name\" does not exist, Query: SELECT round(extract(epoch from ts::timestamptz)/20)*20*1000 AS time_msec, count(column_name.value) FROM public.table_name WHERE ts> (now() - '6h'::interval) GROUP BY round(extract(epoch from ts::timestamptz)/20)*20*1000"
```

Has anyone an idea where the error comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I had to write the `table name` by myself manually and not choose the one proposed by `Grafana`.